# gradle Exec block should not fail for non zero output in

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am writing a gradle task. The task it invokes returns 3 for successful run instead of 3. How do I go about doing this ?

```
task copyToBuildShare(){
   def robocopySourceDir = "build\\outputs\\apk"
   def cmd = "robocopy "+ robocopySourceDir + " C:\\TEST *.* /MIR /R:5 2>&1"
   exec {
      ignoreExitValue = true
      workingDir '.'
      commandLine "cmd", "/c", cmd
      if (execResult.exitValue == 3) {
         println("It probably succeeded")
      }
   }
}
```

It gives the error:

> Could not find property 'execResult' on task

I don't want to create a separate task. I want it to be in the exec block. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Common mistake: do not include the equal sign ('=') between "ignoreExitValue = true".  It should just be 
"ignoreExitValue true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to specify that this task is of type Exec. This is done by specifying the task type like so

```
task testExec(type: Exec) {

}
```

In your specific case, You'll also want to make sure you don't try to get the execResult until the exec has finished this can be done by wrapping the check in a doLast.

```
task testExec(type: Exec) {
    doLast {
        if (execResult.exitValue == 3) {
            println("It probably succeeded")

        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of executing `ls` and checking its return value

```
task printDirectoryContents(type: Exec) {

    workingDir '.'
    commandLine "sh", "-c", "ls"

    doLast{
        if (execResult.exitValue == 0) {
            println("It probably succeeded")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

project.exec() has a return value typed ExecResult.

```
def result = exec {
    ignoreExitValue true 
    executable "cmd"
    args = ["/c", "exit", "1"]
}
println "exit value:"+result.getExitValue()
```

Reference here:

> https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:exec(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: This should really be the answer to the what was asked.  The accepted answer makes a good suggestion but didn't really answer the direct question.  Instead it just gave an alternative way.  At the very least this should be added to the accept answer with the suggestion of the alternate way as a better approach.